# Object.entries splitting function strangely?

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object like this:

```
{
 'icon':'info',
 'size':'small',
 'content':'label'
}
```

I'm trying to split it up into an array of new objects where there is one property per object:

```
{'icon':'info'}, {'size':'small'} , {content':'label}
```

I thought I could do this using Object.entries like this:

```
Object.entries(controlsObject).map(prop => ({ prop }))
```

But it's really not working out for me - is there another way? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Feel free to suggest a totally different solution to the problem - I'm not even sure Object.entries was the right thing to go for here

Comment: `Object.entries` was a fine choice, but read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries); have you tried logging `prop` to see what it is?

Comment: Yes and I was even more confused after haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instead do this:

```js
Object.entries(controlsObject).map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using Object.entries and reduce:

```
const t = {
 'icon':'info',
 'size':'small',
 'content':'label'
}

function objToArr(obj){
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, curr)=>{
    return [...acc, {[curr[0]]:curr[1] }]  
  },[])
}


console.log(objToArr(t)) 

[ { icon: 'info' }, { size: 'small' }, { content: 'label' } ]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use computed property names to construct the object:

```js
const obj = {
 'icon':'info',
 'size':'small',
 'content':'label'
}

const res = Object.entries(obj).map(e => ({ [e[0]]: e[1] }))
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
Object.entries(x).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]:v }))
```

P.S `k` is key and `v` is value